# feasibility of java app for windows and os x

Tags: java, windows, macos

I am writing this app which requires me to list all the Files in a directory and its subdirectories and delete all mp3 file, in Java.

As of now I am using `Apache Commons` libraries and looking for mp3 files like this

```
mp3Files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(path ,new SuffixFileFilter(".mp3"), TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
```

Now the main directory URL i am taking from the user.

Rest of the work my app does.

So what I was wondering is, will the code work the same way for both windows and os x?
will it delete all the mp3 files irrespective of the OS or will the different file structure cause any issue?

Comment: *"will it delete all the mp3 files irrespective of the OS or will the different file structure cause any issue?"*. I can think of one possible issue: directory separators: `\ ` for Windows and `/` for MAC

Comment: oh yes, but that would be provided by the user to the app right? so should there be an issue?

Comment: It really depends on how you write it. Make sure you use `File.separator`, like Vivin points out.

Comment: wouldnt the Apache Commons IO work?

Comment: Sure, and so would the libraries the come packaged in the JDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java is OS agnostic, so you should be fine. But that doesn't mean that your Java code is also OS agnostic. There should be some OS-specific things that you need to take into consideration like separators. This means that you shouldn't hard-code the separator, but use [`File.separator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) instead.

Also, using [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) and not making any assumptions about your environment will help you out as well.

**edit**: Yes, you should be fine using `FileUtils` and searching for MP3 files in that manner.

Comment: I am using external libraries to find the mp3 files. I have edited the code. do take a look.